# Spring Cloud Config Server not working with Docker compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring cloud config server and packaged it as a docker image then I have spring cloud eureka server which is also packaged as docker image.

When I run the two using docker compose I get the following error.

`discovery-service_1  | 2017-06-24 15:36:12.059  INFO 5 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://config-service:9001
discovery-service_1  | 2017-06-24 15:36:12.997  WARN 5 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-service:9001/cls-discovery-service/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

> Although the config service is up and running successfully, discover service still does not find it for some reason.

**Docker compose file being used here is this** 

`version: '2'
services:
        config-service:
                image: cloudsea/cls-config-service
                ports:
                - 9001:9001
                expose:
                - "9001"
        discovery-service:
                image: cloudsea/cls-discovery-service
                depends_on:
                - config-service
                environment:
                        CLOUD_SEA_CONFIG_SERVER_URI: http://config-service:9001
                        EUREKA_DEFAULT_ZONE_URL: http://discovery-service:8761/eureka/
                ports:
                - 8761:8761
                links:
                - config-service:config-service`

Below is the **bootstrap.properties** for DISCOVERY SERVICE

`spring.cloud.config.uri = ${CLOUD_SEA_CONFIG_SERVER_URI:http://localhost:9001}
spring.application.name = ${SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME:cls-discovery-service}`

Below is the **cls-discovery-service.properties** for DISCOVERY SERVICE located in github.

`server.port=${SERVER_PORT:8761}
eureka.client.registerWithEureka: false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry: false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: ${EUREKA_DEFAULT_ZONE_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}
eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000`

I am assuming something is wrong with my docker-compose.yml but I am not sure.

Any help will I am stick in this for hours ... heading close to days :(

Comment: How about running the docker image separately? first run the "config-service", then run the "discovery-service"?

Comment: If I do so it works perfectly but the catch is I have to then specify the config uri as ```http://DOCKER_HOST:9001```. I am assuming the problem is with docker compose but do not know what it is ???

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by adding this configuration to the **discovery service's bootstrap.yml**.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      failFast: true
      retry:
        initialInterval: 3000
        multiplier: 1.3
        maxInterval: 5000
        maxAttempts: 20
```

Then add **spring-boot-starter-aop** and **spring-retry** to the **discovery service's maven dependencies**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-starter-aop.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-retry.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is they're both starting at the same time. But the discovery service depends on the config service.

When you start the discovery service, it's going to say "**Fetching config from server**" again and again until config service is up.

**After the config service starts, discovery service is going to get its configuration successfully** and then it's going to start itself.

Comment: I spend two days facing this problem, so i found this answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is all the docker container will start together, but as per your architecture, the config-service needs to start first, then the discovery-service(eureka). So discovery-service is giving the error.

`depends_on` **does not wait for config-service to be “ready” before starting discovery-service - it only waits until it is started**. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, you have to use **controlling startup order**.

**As suggested about you can set the APIs/Services to keep retrying in some intervals until the config server is up**.

Although, I would also prefer to use depends_on or healthcheck and controlling startup order as shown below:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

wait-for-it.sh is a pure bash script that will wait on the availability. I would also suggest looking into, **container orchestration tools like docker-swarm or kubernetes**.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue and was stuck for a bit and I was about to go the same route as you did with the spring retry, which isn't a bad pattern to follow it does embed resiliency into your application but the main issue here is docker's launch order is out of place. I'll share my working docker-compose file, it's quite similar but the key here is the "depends_on" parameter. I've added quotes on my arguments and it seemed to work.

```js
version: "2"
services:
  eureka:
    image: eurekatest
    ports:
    - "8761:8761"

  config: 
    image: config
    ports:
    - "8888:8888"
    links:
    - eureka:eureka
    depends_on:
    - "eureka"
```